# Why do I have to earn a reputation to provide a legit answer?

Tags: discussion

I found a solution to a "hot question" and want to share the answer, so I joined this site. But, the powers that be have deemed me unworthy of providing said answer bc I'm new. Great. So I'll write this question to earn my "reputation" points. What a joke.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Could you provide a link to the question you wanted to answer? There is no minimum reputation required to answer questions typically, unless a question is protected.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50779/illustrator-how-to-change-the-artboard-number

Comment: And to Scott, I appreciate the link, but the whole issue is that answering questions is a "privilege" which can only be unlocked by asking questions. 
So I, as a new member, who came here to provide an answer to a question all the "privileged" haven't been able to find a solution for, have been kept out unless I ask questions. It actively prohibits new insight. I'd rather post the answer somewhere that welcomes my input rather than gatekeeping the only thing people come here for: answers.

Comment: @ezage No it can also be unlocked by answering normal questions. Protected questions are a bit special, but also rare.

Comment: @ezage I unprotected it temporarily since I'm around to keep an eye. Just make sure that your answer really adds to what's already there because there are quite a few bad answers deleted on that question that you cannot see.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes when a post goes to the "Hot Network" it gets a lot of attention. This attracts all kinds of very low quality answers that aren't much better than comments, repeating what has been said or even downright misguided answers.

To lower the burden on the curating part of the community the question can get protected (by vote or automatically) so that people need to have some minimum number of score to answer.

Its possible to reverse this protection but we would need to know what question it is you want to answer. Another way is to answer to another questions instead and get the needed score. Unfortunately you don't get any score for this post since its a meta issue (a issue of how the site works), and meta does not award score. So on meta score is more a voting structure than moderation.

Comment: This whole site has been frustrating. I can't even upvote your answer bc I don't have points. 
Edit: "You earn points by asking a question" (asks a question) "No not that type of question" I even tried to tag this question as "Meta" but I couldn't bc.... guess what? You need points to create a new tag. ffs. 
Now I see my question got moved to a "meta" section? That would've been nice to know about. 
Then, is this part of stackoverflow? I found it though graphicdesign stack exchange, which Idk what that is. Signing up was a terrible UX.

Comment: @ezage The reason people need points to do actions other than asking and answering unprotected stuff around is so that people learn how the site works before going around breaking things (even if the intentions are good). I agree the UX is super frustrating. Unfortunately that's not in our hands.